# Ordered triple condition

Tags: combinatorics

Compute the number of ordered triples $(a,b,c)$ of positive integers such that
$$a2^b + b2^c + c2^a = 2000.$$

I tried to make some bijection but no luck.
I have tried setting some variables to see if stars and bars (or balls and urns) works, as well as casework counting.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Can you find at least one triple that satisfies this? Start from getting an example, this will be helpful.

Comment: Since $a,b,c \le 10$ it's not hard to compute by brute force.

Comment: I know it not hard to brute force, but I wish to have a general method rather than that (what is it was equal to 200000?) I also added what I tried.

Comment: $200000$ is also easy.  You only need to go up to $17$.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Since there are no examples, that's not so helpful.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Oh, that's unfortunate. I wouldn't know how to prove it without some brute force.

Comment: $7\le \max(a,b,c) \le 10$, so not many cases.

Comment: And $\min(a,b,c) \le 4$

Answer (score 1):

On investigation numerically, there are no positive integer triples $(a,b,c)$ for which the function $ f(a,b,c) := a2^b + b2^c + c2^a$ fulfils the condition
$$  f(a,b,c) = 2\cdot 10^k $$
for any value of $k\in \mathbb N$ up to $600$.

Allowing $a,b,c$ to also be zero (but forbidding any of $2^a, 2^b, 2^c$ to be greater than the target value) gives us effectively one solution in that space, $f(1,4,0) = 20$, so also $(4,0,1)$ and $(0,1,4)$.

The closest approach to the original problem (where $k=3$) is $f(5,8,6)=1984$

---

I might have become a little obsessed with the form $a2^b + b2^c + c2^a$ ...

Anyway the original format above has no solutions out to $2\cdot 10^{10000}$.

I also had a quick look at variations in the form $a2^b + b2^c + c2^a = N^k$ (just for fun) and

- $4\cdot 2^5 +5\cdot 2^3 +3\cdot 2^4 = 6^3$  (quite pretty, all low numbers)
- $13\cdot 2^{17}+ 17\cdot 2^{14} + 14\cdot 2^{13} = 8^7$, weirdly
- $3\cdot 2^9 +  9\cdot 2^7 +  7\cdot 2^3 = 14^3$ and
- $2\cdot 2^7 + 7\cdot 2^3 + 3\cdot 2^2 = 18^2$